# How to recover from an unwanted rename using git-svn: "Transaction is out of date"

Tags: git-svn

I'm using git-svn. I've moved file 'A' to 'B' and I'm up to date with the svn HEAD (using `git svn rebase`). I can commit all other changes without problems. Now I've decided that I want to move 'B' back to 'A' and commit that change.

When I do the move and commit to my local master it works fine, but I get the following when doing a `git svn dcommit`:

```
Transaction is out of date: Out of date: 'A' in transaction '3652-1' at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 570
```

So I tried to copy and delete in a separate commit which resulted in:

```
Item already exists in filesystem: File already exists: filesystem '/usr/svn/db', transaction '3652-1', path 'A' at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4735
```

I've recovered from this situation with plain svn by using the workarounds like the one described in the [documentation](https://svn.haxx.se/subusers/archive-2005-02/0096.shtml), but I don't know how to recover with git-svn. What is going on and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing .git/svn did not work for me. Instead, here's how I resolved:

- Deleted the offending directories from the repository (But I'm not sure that this is necessary. In hindsight I think I could have skipped this step)
- `git svn rebase`
- During the rebase, there were some conflicts. For each conflict, I resolved the conflicts in text editor, then used `git add <file-in-conflict>` and then `git rebase --continue`
- After rebase completed successfully, `git svn dcommit` ran successfully!

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this works (too)? Seems like it got a downvote, but I don't know why.

Comment: @iwein: This one worked for me and the accepted answer did not.

Comment: This worked for me too, and I didn't need first step (Deleting offending directories).

Comment: Worked for me, without first step.

Answer (score 4):

I can't claim to understand what's really going on under the hood in `git-svn` in this case (although the underlying SVN issue makes perfect sense).  My usual strategy when `git-svn` gets confused somehow is to blow away the `.git/svn` metadata directory (as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135477/git-svn-rebase-resulted-in-byte-order-is-not-compatible-error/3311742#3311742)).  This almost always saves me from odd synchronization issues between the git and SVN repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Could you provide a little detail on how the svn issue makes perfect sense? I'll try to reproduce it and see if blowing away the .git/svn directory works. I vaguely recall that I actually did a fresh clone and the issue was still there.

Comment: It looks like an issue of a "mixed revision" working copy, where some part of the working copy has been updated to a different, older revision than the rest of the WC.  But I can't really tell which parts are out of date.  This is partly described here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs.  Did the metadata removal trick work for you?

Comment: I didn't manage to test it anymore due to the volatility of my local code bases. Let's assume that it works until someone finds that it doesn't :)

Comment: I'm getting the same "Item already exists", but unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I'll add an answer if I find a work around

Answer (score 0):

It happened with me when I interrupted the `dcommit` process.

Follow these steps to recover from error:

1. `git svn rebase`
2. You will get conflicts in files. Resolve the conflicts & then `git add filename` (in which conflict occurred) for each file.
3. Now do `git svn dcommit`. It will be pushed to remote successfully.

Comment: Interesting detail. But the recipe is the same as the accepted answer.