# git svn rebase resulted in "byte order is not compatible" error

Tags: perl, git-svn, compatibility, rebase, endianness

Following is the error I am getting when I tried 'git svn rebase':

```
Byte order is not compatible at ../../lib/Storable.pm (autosplit into ../../lib/auto/Storable/_retrieve.al) line 380, at /usr/lib/perl5/5.10/Memoize/Storable.pm line 21
```

The version of perl I am running is:

```
$ perl --version

This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-cygwin-thread-multi-64int
(with 12 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

When I searched the web for "*Byte order is not compatible*" and I get numerous hits that shows the Perl doc that says:

> What this means is that if you have
>   data written by Storable 1.x running
>   on perl 5.6.0 or 5.6.1 configured with
>   64 bit integers on Unix or Linux then
>   by default this Storable will refuse
>   to read it, giving the error Byte
>   order is not compatible. If you have
>   such data then you you should set
>   $Storable::interwork_56_64bit to a
>   true value to make this Storable read
>   and write files with the old header.
>   You should also migrate your data, or
>   any older perl you are communicating
>   with, to this current version of
>   Storable.

What I don't know is, how to set this '`$Storable::interwork_56_64bit`' to true. Can you please let me know how to do it?

Comment: Both answers from @Dave-Goodell and @Jacques works fine. But the method suggested by @Dave-Goodell takes quite a long time especially if the svn repo is huge. In such cases, blowing away the `.git/svn/.caches` folder helps. I recently encountered the problem. Tried the answer from @Dave-Goodell but it took forever so I killed it. Restored the backed up `.git/svn` folder and then tried the answer by @Jacques. It resolved the problem in lot lesser time frame.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I started getting this error message. I'm using a git repository that lives in a Max OS X partition. I sometimes access it from OS X (64 bit), and sometimes access it from a VM that's running a 32 bit version of Linux. It looks like there's a cache file that is stored in a machine-dependent format.

After doing some digging, I believe you can work around the error by blowing away all of the .db files stored in .git/svn/.caches. This should be a slightly more surgical approach than blowing away the entire svn directory.

Comment: This also resolved my Windows->Ubuntu transplanted git repository, but my error was 'Long integer size is not compatible at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/Storable.pm line 379, at /usr/share/perl/5.14.2/Memoize/Storable.pm line 21
Could not unmemoize function `lookup_svn_merge', because it was not memoized to begin with at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 3588
END failed--call queue aborted at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 39.' This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
 Took about 10 minutes, but that may just've been the outstanding download from svn.

Comment: This also helped me after upgrading my 32bit openSUSE to 64bit

Comment: Something was updated (Ubuntu-LTS) and I got this problem. This trick works like magic!

Answer (score 17):

This happened to me recently on my Mac.  I'm not sure what caused it, but the standard git-svn "fix" of blowing away the metadata and updating worked for me:

```
% mv .git/svn .git/svn.bak
% git svn fetch
Migrating from a git-svn v1 layout...
Data from a previous version of git-svn exists, but
        .git/svn
        (required for this version (1.7.1) of git-svn) does not exist.
Done migrating from a git-svn v1 layout
Rebuilding .git/svn/refs/remotes/bg-threads-1.1/.rev_map.a5d90c62-d51d-0410-9f91-bf5351168976 ...
r5758 = 545e176a13e87d44a2750ff5f06959088efc9e5b
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect one potential cause of this is using a git repository with svn data that's been fetched on one machine and then subsequently archived up and downloaded for use on another machine.

In my case it was fetched on CentOS and then transplanted to an Ubuntu machine - both 64-bit installs but perhaps some little detail of their Perl configuration is different. Or perhaps a package update changed something.