# `git svn dcommit` failing on a branch

Tags: branch, git-svn, cherry-pick, dcommit

I have been using `git-svn` to communicate with my company’s svn repo for a while now without any major headaches.

Today, the “headache”-part changed dramatically:
I’ve been working on `master/trunk` pretty exclusively, and needed to merge most (but not all!) of those change-sets into a new svn-branch, that originated from a pre-existing svn-branch.

Basically this:

```
-----------1--1-----1--------1--1--1---  master/trunk
 \
  \
   2--2--2--2--2                                        versioned-release
```

Should have become this:

```
-----------1--1-----1--------1--1--1---  master/trunk
 \
  \
   2--2--2--2--2                                        versioned-release
                         \
                          \
                           1--1--1--1--1--1           new-versioned-release
```

Where  are commits that shouldn’t be in the `new-versioned-release`, and `x` the wanted commits from the respective branches `x`.

So I did the following:

1. `git checkout -b versioned-release-svn remotes/versioned-release`
2. `git svn branch new-versioned-release -m "Preparing for merge of XXX"`
3. `git checkout -b new-versioned-release-svn remotes/new-versioned-release`
4. `git cherry-pick ...` for every `1`, resolving any conflicts on the way.

Because I wanted to be sure I was really going to target the correct branch on the repo, I then ran `git svn dcommit --dry-run` which did not yield any errors or warnings, but told me…

```
Committing to svn://username@$repo-host/$repo-name/$path/branches/new-versioned-release ...
```

…followed by a couple of `diff-tree` lines.

So I attempted to omit the `--dry-run` and half way through the commits ended up with…

```
Item already exists in filesystem: File already exists: filesystem '/data/subvroot/$repo-name/db', transaction '20856-g3m', path '/$path/branches/new-versioned-release/some-directory' at /usr/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 862
```

…and a **bunch** of unstaged changes.

Apart from the obvious — “WTF?!?” and “How do I get out of this mess without losing everything I did?” — I have two questions:

1. Assuming I was back to before `git svn dcommit`: How do I get my local branch dcommit to its planned destination?
2. By now it seems obvious, that this wasn’t the right way to achieve what I wanted…but *how* should I have done it, instead?

Everything I found for the error-message, that somehow resembled my situation, so far was [this other stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922059/how-to-recover-from-an-unwanted-rename-using-git-svn-transaction-is-out-of-dat) and the proposed solution of “somehow […] to blow away the `.git/svn` metadata directory” doesn’t resonate quite *that* well with me…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone just up–voted my old question, so I thought I’d share how I do that nowadays.

It works really quite well.

Assuming the git repository has been created using

```
git svn clone \
    --prefix svn/ \
    --stdlayout \
    svn://username@$repo-host/$repo-name/$path
    $git_repo_name
```

change into the git repo, and there run

```
git checkout svn/versioned-release
git svn branch new-versioned-release
```

This will result in the following history on the SVN server:

```
-----------1--1-----1--------1--1--1---  trunk
 \
  \
   2--2--2--2--2                                        versioned-release
                          \
                           \
                            3⭐️                                    new-versioned-release
```

Now I’d run

```
git checkout svn/new-versioned-release
git checkout -b new-versioned-release

# resulting in the following **local** history:
#
# -----------1--1-----1--------1--1--1---  master (tracks 'svn/trunk')
#  \
#   \
#    2--2--2--2--2--3⭐️                         new-versioned-release (tracks 'svn/new-versioned-release')
```

This is the foundation for achieving what I wanted.

There is one additional commit, because branching in SVN doesn’t work the same way as in Git: creating a branch always means a new revision, (aka commit) and that’s where the `3⭐️` comes from. It doesn’t really matter, but it’s there.

I can now `git cherry-pick` all the `1`s, ending up with this local history:

```
-----------1--1-----1--------1--1--1---  master (tracks 'svn/trunk')
 \
  \
   2--2--2--2--2--3⭐️--1--1--1--1--1--1  new-versioned-release (tracks 'svn/new-versioned-release')
```

When I now `git svn dcommit` while sitting on `new-versioned-release` in git, the history on the SVN server looks like what I wanted to end up with:

```
-----------1--1-----1--------1--1--1---  trunk
 \
  \
   2--2--2--2--2                                        versioned-release
                          \
                           \
                            3⭐️--1--1--1--1--1--1    new-versioned-release
```

The only difference being that additional `3⭐️` from creating the third SVN branch.